# Oracle convert to utf8

Tags: oracle, utf-8

Converting to utf8 in oracle by using the CONVERT function wotks fine only for a caracter "**è**" :

```
    select convert('è','UTF8') from dual;
```

and the result is "**Ãš**"

If we try to convert with PHP, the result is différent only for this caracter

```
    echo utf8_encode('è');
```

it displays "**Ã¨**" and this is the correct result.

I saw the documentation for CONVERT and tried many options with no success.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Convert from which encoding? And why in the first place? If you have a web site powered by PHP you don't need to do any conversion by yourself.

Comment: I have a lot of data returned by an oracle sql query, and I don't want to apply on this data a PHP function (array_map or array_walk)  for conversion.

Comment: convert from iso-8859-1 and even if I specify this in function parameters , it changes nothing

Comment: If you are using [oci_connect()](http://php.net/oci_connect), you have to populate the 4th parameter.

Comment: What do you actually try to achieve? Did you check [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions041.htm) where it says: *Oracle discourages the use of the CONVERT function in the current Oracle Database release. [...] Therefore, the only practical use of the function is to correct data that has been stored in a wrong character set.* Is this the case you do just have a display issue?

Comment: I think that's a good answer, that oracle discourages it. Well my goal is not to correct data but to convert it, I will rely on PHP to do this..Thank you all

Comment: No, don't do it with PHP either. Just declare the connection encoding and let Oracle take care of it automatically.